# I am unable to edit gedit ~/.bashrc in ubuntu please help how to do

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, hadoop

I am installing hadoop  in ubuntu 19 and I am trying  to  edit bashrc file in gedit but unable to  edit gedit bashrc file please help me how to do.
This my hduser dir:

```
 hdusr@suri-VirtualBox
```

when I  am sitting the path to  hadoop in gedit, It throughs an error.

```
hdusr@suri-VirtualBox:/home/suri/Desktop$ sudo gedit
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(org.gnome.gedit:26356): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:44:15.925: cannot open display:
```

after that i tried xhost + but didn't work for me please help me how to fix it.

Comment: Don't use sudo to edit .bashrc

Comment: Is this a desktop or server installation in the VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo nano ~/.bashrc` to edit .bashrc file . Then reload the file using  `source ~./bashrc`

Answer (score -2):

1. if u are using sudo means, you are going to change root .bashrc file because 
    of that may be u are not able to change file.
2. check once display environment is there or not and to set environment follow 
    these commands -

   **DISPLAY=":0" 
      export DISPLAY**